# calculate the percentage of substring occurrence in string, python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've written a function that works for strings of length 1, but I have no idea how to make it work for longer ones.

```
def function(text, n):
    dict={}
    char_count=0

    for c in text:
        keys=dict.keys()
        if c.isalpha()==True:
            char_count+=1
            if c in keys:
                dict[c] +=1
            else:
                dict[c]=1
    for key in dict:
        dict[key]=dict[key]/char_count

    return dict
```

The use of import is not very welcome :/

Comment: HINT: Split the string first using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), then count the number of differently sized elements in the resulting list.

Comment: It appears that someone down-voted each of the answers; please explain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a generator than iterates over each substring of length `n`.  Then use them as keys to a dictionary that tracks the counts.

```
def substring_percentage(text, n):
    out = {}
    n_substrings = len(text)-n+1
    subs = (text[i:i+n] for i in range(n_substrings))
    for s in subs:
        if s in out:
            out[s] += 100 / n_substrings
        else:
            out[s] = 100 / n_substrings
    return out
```

Tests:

```
s = 'I have an assignment to write a function that will receive a sentence and a number ' \
  +'and will return the percentage of the occurrences of strings of length of the given ' \
  +'number in the given string.'

pcts = substring_percentage(s, 4)
sorted(pcts.items(), key=lambda x: x[::-1], reverse=True)
# returns:
[('the ', 2.094240837696335),
 (' the', 2.094240837696335),
 (' of ', 2.094240837696335),
 ('n th', 1.5706806282722514),
 ...
 (' an ', 0.5235602094240838),
 (' a s', 0.5235602094240838),
 (' a n', 0.5235602094240838),
 (' a f', 0.5235602094240838)]
```

Comment: but how do i make the function not count spaces with your solution?

Comment: As in remove spaces such that `'i am a hat' -> 'iamahat'`?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just didn't want the function to count substrings that had spaces in them so i added an if before the addition to the dictionary :)

Answer (score -1):

Three steps:

- Split the input into individual words; Python's `split` function will return a nice list for you.
- Make a corresponding list of word lengths; use `len` on each element.
- Use the `count` function to count the occurrences of each length; put those results in a dictionary.

For instance, if you start with:

```
sentence = "Now I will a rhyme construct "       + \
           "By chosen words the young instruct " + \
           "Cunningly ensured endeavour "        + \
           "Con it and remember ever "           + \
           "Widths of circle here you see "      + \
           "Stretchd out in strange obscurity "
```

Split this into individual words.  List the length of each word; it would look like this:

```
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 
 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 
 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 
 3, 3, 8, 3, 2, 7, 9]
```

Then you count how many of each number are in this list.
Does that get you moving?